# how to ensure the parent model doesn't save when child model validation fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

```
class User < ApplicationRecord 
  has_many :books
  delegate :title,:pages,:paragraphs to: book_attributes
end

class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  validates :title, length: { maximum: 35}

end
```

when I create a User with the associated books even though the book validation is wrong ie I create a title with more than 35 characters the user is saved .

> How do i ensure that the users aren't saved when the validation of the
>   book model have failed .

Answer (score 0):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  user = User.new(user_params)
  book = Book.new(book_params)
  user.save!
  book.save!
end
```

Interesting that your user relies on books to be valid in order to be created, but you could use [Transaction](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html) in Rails. This only saves to DB if nothing raises an exception in the block.

Comment: it did not work. but i have solved it . The trick was to make the book to save first before the user. there is a little bit of rails majic in between . And when creating the book create User.books.create(book_params) .